# How to Integrate admob with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

I have been trying to integrate flutter with admob and i did update my manifest.xml file with the meta tags and everything, i followed the tutorial provided by pub.dev and nothing works. It sends a compile error saying implementation of plugin firebase.admob failed. If any one practically ran into this problem or can provide me with detailed steps to integrate i would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the initialization code inside initstate(), thanks and sorry tor the inconvenience.